# How to wait for previous steps to finish

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am designing an ETL with spoon from Pentaho.

[image: ETL Flow]

My purpose is to execute 'Calculate Value' after 'Load To Database' and 'Update Database'.

What step should be used to replace '??? Step wait' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace ??? step wait with a dummy step.
then after that have a "Block rows on step"

Answer (score 3):

You could move the "Calculate Value" step into a new transformation and create a job to execute this after the first transformation is completed.